# For 2 to LastRow - not working

Tags: excel, vba

It's like it doesn't read LastRow as a Number! Help!! this is my code:

```
Sub DD()

Dim rNum As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Rows.Count

For rNum = 2 To LastRow    
  Select Case Range("D" & rNum).Value
    Case "FXD"
      Range("P" & rNum).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-13]"
   Case Else
     Range("P" & rNum).Value = -4

End Select
Next rNum       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Rows.Count
```

to this:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
```

You wanted `Row` rather than `Rows.Count` (which would always be 1 since you were referring to one cell) and it's generally better to go up from the bottom of the sheet, rather than down.

Comment: another question sorry, I thought you had omitted the "s" in ".Row" then I put it in the code, as a result I got the formula computed till row 41639! Why is it? what's the difference of Row with the s or without? thanks in advance

Comment: `Row` returns a row *number* whereas `Rows` returns a Range object representing all rows in the specified range.